# App crashing on iphone over physics body issue

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2

Whenever I try to run my app on my phone, it crashes with the following error:

```
[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:size:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3989f880.
```

I know it's happening because of this line of code

```
object.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "object"),  size: object.size)
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Does the image exist?

Comment: the image definitely exists and this is the only line of code thats crashing the program. When i change it everything is working regular

Comment: _this is the only line of code thats crashing the program_, however, this is not the only line of code thats consisting of the program. Good luck.

Comment: @user302692 Which iOS do you have installed on device? Method bodyWithTexture: size: is iOS 8 only...

Comment: oh shoot i have ios 7.2. #neverupdatedever